# Get facebook like click in new windows with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to get facebook like click button on a new window that my website will open.
When click on the like button I want to show a thank you message.

I try:

```
<script>
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=ID", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");
}

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    alert("thank you for like");
});​

</script>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open facebook to like post</button>
```

but it is not working. what is wrong?

Comment: `it is not working` isn't exactly something we can work with. What do you expect? What do you observe? Do you get any errors in the console? How is `FB.Event.subscribe` related to the issue?

Comment: the alert message is not showing. console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined

Comment: `FB is not defined` - clearly some (facebook) javascript library hasn't been loaded

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the JavaScript SDK is loaded correctly BEFORE using FB.Event.subscribe: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.4

For example:

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'your-app-id',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.4'
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
            alert("thank you for like");
        });​
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```